# Not able to see the print message after creating ObjectInputStream

Tags: java

I have written the following program.As you can see I have put a print message after the creation of ObjectInputStream object ois.I have a server That is opened on Port 9090.As you can see from the above netstat message

```
sudo netstat -al | grep 9090
tcp6       0      0 [::]:9090               [::]:*                  LISTEN
```

I don't know why the print message is displayed on the screen.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.lang.ClassNotFoundException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class MyClient {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int count = 0;
        try {
            /*
             * Create a connection to the server socket on the server application
             */
             InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
             Socket socket = new Socket(address, 9090);

            /*
             * Read and display the response message sent by server application
             */
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            System.out.println("Created client socket and Input Stream Reader");
            while (true) {
                if (count < 1000) {
                    String message = (String) ois.readObject();
                    System.out.println("OFMessage: " + message);
                    count++;
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
            ois.close();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "I don't know why the print message is displayed on the screen." or it must be "I don't know why the print message is not displayed on the screen."?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constructor to `ObjectInputStream` reads from the stream - it reads the header information, basically.

So if the server you're talking to hasn't *written* any data, your program will just sit there, waiting until the header is actually written.

If you hit break in a debugger when running this code, I think you'll find the stack trace includes `ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader`.

Comment: Only you would know this, Mr. Skeet.

Comment: @tbodt: I didn't *know* it - I *researched* it. (It doesn't take long to open up Eclipse and look through the `ObjectInputStream` constructor.)